# .Net MAUI Android: How to Collect GPS Position when App is Closed or Inactive?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, maui

My goal is to write GPS data in a GPX file while my app is not in forground, even then when screensaver is on.
I tried a lot of samples with *Foreground/Background Service* and *AlarmManager* all found in the internet.
They all work fine as long as the app is visible. A few of them even run when app is invisible - but only on the emulator!
I could not find **any** .Net MAUI sample **working correct on a REAL DEVICE**!
I tested on devices with Android 11 - API30 and Android 13 - API33

Folks, please do not answer like this: "*After a quick research I found ...*"  I realy tried a lot of them.
I would be very happy to see a working sample, thanks!

Comment: `Android 11 - API30 and Android 13 - API33` ? You mean: `Android 11 - SDK 30 and Android 13 - SDK 33` ?